# Airy differential equation and Galois group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ordinary-differential-equations, algebraic-topology, algebraic-groups

Consider the Airy equation $y^{(2)}=ry$ where $r \in \Bbb{C}(z)$ but not constant. How do you show that $G^0=G$, where $G$ is the galois group of the picard vessiot extension of solutions over $\Bbb{C}(z)$ and $G^0$ is its connected component. It would be helpful if someone could give me some reference for this fact.

Comment: One of Lie’s motivations for studying Lie groups was to extend Galois theory to
diﬀerential equations, by studying the symmetry groups of diﬀerential equations. [notes](http://math.berkeley.edu/~reb/courses/261/12.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

This differential Galois group $G$ of the Airy equation is $SL_2$. Therefore it is connected, i.e. $G = G^0$.

It is computed for example in Examples 4.29 of [1]. See also example 6.21.

[1] Andy R. Magid. Lectures on differential Galois theory, volume 7 of University Lecture Series. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 1994.